# Is there any problem with Beamer 3.50?

Tags: beamer

Beamer (beamer 2018/02/20 v3.50) overlays are nor aligning anymore. How to fix it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Foo}  

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]\frametitle{Foo}
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics<1>{figure1.pdf}
        \includegraphics<2>{figure2.pdf}
        \includegraphics<3>{figure3.pdf}
        \includegraphics<4>{figure4.pdf}
        \includegraphics<5>{figure5.pdf}            
        \includegraphics<6>{figure6.pdf}
    \end{figure}    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: crosspost: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/475

Comment: Are you sure the PDF have the same dimensions?