# TeX Recompiles Differently on my Computer

Tags: beamer, graphics, compiling

I'm using MacTex (2018) and am running into an issue when trying to compile a beamer presentation that somebody sent me. When I compile on ShareLatex or if they compile it (Also using MacTex) they get the following slide: 
[image: Proper Image]

Whenever I compile the exact same code I get this:

[image: Bad Image]

I tried doing a clean install, but I'm still running into the same issue.

Update::

Code for the slide:

```
\frame{
\frametitle{Example $S^1$: Eigenvector Decomposition $L = U \Lambda U^\top$} 
\vspace{-10pt}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 0.33\linewidth]{Figs/Lmatrix.png} \\
{\huge $=$}
\includegraphics[width = 0.34\linewidth]{Figs/Umatrix.png}
\includegraphics[width = 0.33\linewidth]{Figs/LambdaMatrix.png}
\includegraphics[width = 0.335\linewidth]{Figs/UTmatrix.png} \\
\hspace{20pt}{\huge $U$ \hspace{70pt} $\Lambda$ \hspace{70pt} $U^\top$}
\end{figure}
  }
```

Praemable:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bchart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{movie15}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{float}
\usetheme{default}
```

Comment: Compare the versions you are having. I bet mactex isn't running a recent version.

Comment: I think I'm running the most recent version. When I run TeX in terminal it says: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=tex)

Comment: But ShareLaTeX is not known for keeping their TeX distro fully up-to-date. And maybe the person you got this from does not regularly update either.

Comment: @AneeshMalhotra Can you show the code for this slide?

Comment: Added the code for the slide!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short summary: you are missing % signs at the end of a few lines (beamer seems to be more picky about that in recent versions, see also [Is there any problem with Beamer 3.50?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428579/is-there-any-problem-with-beamer-3-50)).

Some other comments:

- The sum of the combined image widths is also a bit too large. Adjust the numbers to be smaller than 1.
- You don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` nor `\usetheme{default}`
- The `float` package does not make much sense in a documentclass without floats
- `movie15` is obsolete and should not be used any more. Try `media9` instead.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bchart}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{epsfig}
%\usepackage{movie15}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{animate}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usetheme{default}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\frametitle{Example $S^1$: Eigenvector Decomposition $L = U \Lambda U^\top$} 
\vspace{-10pt}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 0.33\linewidth]{example-image} \\
{\huge $=$}
\includegraphics[width = 0.33\linewidth]{example-image}%
\includegraphics[width = 0.33\linewidth]{example-image}%
\includegraphics[width = 0.33\linewidth]{example-image}\\
\hspace{20pt}{\huge $U$ \hspace{70pt} $\Lambda$ \hspace{70pt} $U^\top$}
\end{figure}
  }


\end{document}
```

Comment: @AneeshMalhotra You're welcome!

Comment: @AneeshMalhotra If the answer worked for you, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark left of it.